# I cannot paint in the "Texture Paint" mode

Tags: texturing, uv, blender-internal-render-engine, texture-painting, texture-paint-mode

I'm trying for hours to use the "Texture Paint" mode in the right side.

But unfortunatelyI can't paint, I checked the slots, but with no successed.

The left side, works ok!

Can you help me please?

[Blender Project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bS0uTrPTpXYi5oN_2nLkg_apA2gKwOeE)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like inverted normals, try selecting that mesh and pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>
 or <kbd>W</kbd>>`Flip Normals`